# Visual Studio Debuggins

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I believe I seen it but cannot figure out where.

Say I have the following code:

```
     if(c == 6)...
```

What I like to do is to thorugh the debugger set c  to say 5 and see what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a breakpoint on  the `if`, thus stopping execution *before* it gets executed, and in the command window type `c=5`.

Alternatively, put a watch on `c` and double click its value in the watch window. You can then set it to whatever you want (should work with the quick watch window too).

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way to do it is to set your breakpoint and when the debugger has stopped at it, mouse over the variable and in the popup window where it shows you the value, you can click the value and change it there. It's good for small adjustments.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the MSDN documentation [How to: Edit a Value in a Variable Window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa6fy2x5.aspx), explaining how to achieve what you want to do, plus more interesting relevant information.